# Index field is mapped as text instead of keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

Experiencing an issue with ES, 
I have a mapping for a user type, specifying a field as keyword

`GET _template/user_template`

Returns:

```
{
 ...
 "primary_user": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
}
```

The following filter request will return with hits

```
GET users/user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "primary_user.keyword": "AWBFyulcxxxxxxxx"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following request will return with 0 hits.

```
GET users/user/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "primary_user": "AWBFyulcxxxxxxxx"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

From the Dev tools autocomplete, I can see the ES regards the `primary_user` as text.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the name of the index with the template index pattern: the template will be applied only to index with name matching the index pattern.

In addition templates are only applied at index creation time and changing a template will have no impact on existing indices: if you have updated the template, you have to create a new index (ord deleting and recreating an existing one) for viewing the changes in the mapping.